# Search in object for the first element of an array to get field name

Tags: javascript

How can I search in this object/array for the first elements to get the field name?

In this example I need to get `second` if I am searching for `#999999`

```
colors = { 
    first: ['#cccccc', '#999999'],
    second: ['#999999', '#626262'],
    third: ['#eeeeee', '#afafaf']
};
```

I tried something like this:

```
for(var field in colors) {
    if(colors.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
        if(colors[field] === '#999999') {
            console.log(field); // gives 'second'
            var color1 = colors[field][0],
                color2 = colors[field][1];
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe this could get more simplified.

Comment: _"In this example I need to get second if I am searching for #999999"_ Both `first` and `second` arrays contain `"#999999"`

Comment: @guest271314 `Search in object for the first element`

Comment: @SimonH, nope, this not guaranteed: [_The loop will iterate over **all** enumerable properties of the object itself and **those the object inherits from its constructor's prototype**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: @guest271314: For the search I just want to look at the first array element

Comment: Keep in mind that the order of iteration via `for...in` is not guaranteed, i.e. different browsers might iterate over the properties in different order. Thus it isn't really correct to say "the first" property. I think the most popular browsers iterate over non-numeric properties in insertion order, but that's an implementation detail.

Comment: If you just want to look at the `first` property you don't need a loop.

Comment: @FelixKling, methinks, OP mean **first** as first element in array: `['#cccccc', '#999999']`

Comment: @Grundy: That makes sense as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Object.keys()` , `Array.prototype.filter()` ; return property name of object where `"#999999"` is at index `0` of array

```js
var colors = {
  first: ['#cccccc', '#999999'],
  second: ['#999999', '#626262'],
  third: ['#eeeeee', '#afafaf']
};

var n = "#999999";

var res = Object.keys(colors).filter(function(key, index) {
  return colors[key][0] === n
});

console.log(res[0])
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is not a backward compatible solution.

Comment: seems, instead `colors[key].indexOf(n) === 0` better `colors[key][0] === n`

Comment: @user3142695 _"But this gives me the array as result, not the field name..."_ Is expected result `colors` property name `second` ?

Comment: yes, result should be `second`. Anik Islam Abhi deleted the answer: `var name=Object.keys(colors).find(function(x){ return colors[x][0] == "#999999"; });`

Answer (score 0):

`colors[field]` is the entire Array. You forgot to test against the Array element. Your loop should look more like:

```
for(var field in colors){
  if(colors[field][0] === '#999999'){
    console.log(field); // gives 'second'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all the key names with that search parameter in that array position, use an array to capture them. Here's a generic function to solve that just in case you have more than one array with that param in that position.

```
function find(obj, param, pos) {
   var out = [];
   for (var p in obj) {
     if (obj[p][pos] === param) out.push(p);
   }
   return out;
}

find(colors, '#999999', 0); // ['second']
find(colors, '#999999', 1); // ['first']
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y0mc28Lf/4/)

Comment: if you know concrete position, why needed `indexOf` and not just check value for this position?